# Маппинг сущностей в DTO и обратно. Что используется в коммерческой разработке?

Tags: java, rest, dto, mapping

Смотрел код разных учебных программ и обратил внимание, что на одну сущность может приходится несколько разных ДТО. При этом, преобразование в ДТО и обратно осуществлялось разными способами, видел следующие варианты:

- Ручное создание Мапперов с использованием аннотации @Builder из Lombok для чистоты и лаконичности кода.
- использование MapStruct
- использование ModelMapper

Подскажите какой способ является наиболее предпочтительным и распространенным в реальных проектах?
Спасибо!

Comment: На такой вопрос нельзя дать однозначный ответ, так как он будет основан на мнениях / предпочтениях.  В каком-нибудь особо кровавом энтерпрайзе и Ломбок может не использоваться, а только "чистые" сеттеры/геттеры :)  Также в качестве DTO можно использовать добавленные относительно недавно кортежи (record).

Comment: Частное мнение: если делается с нуля - то MapStruct, но в ряде случаев для простоты восприятия используется plain-преобразование обычными методами, ибо MapStruct далеко не всегда прозрачен с кастомными вычислениями. ModelMapper из-за его эвристики и работы непосредственно в рантайме должен (но не факт) проигрывать в производительности статически сгенерированному коду. Lombok - всегда и везде :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, для конвертации DTO MapStruct удобнее